# Haskell gtk Install Type Conflicts

Tags: macos, haskell, gtk, haskell-platform, threadscope

The basic problem:

I'm attempting to install Haskell's [`gtk`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk) package using the [standard mac instructions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Gtk2Hs/Mac) on OSX 10.10.4.  Specifically, I want to run [`threadscope`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threadscope), so I need [`gtk`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk). Early stages with `homebrew` and the `gtk buildtools` work fine, but when I

```
cabal install gtk
```

or use

```
cabal install --with-gcc=gcc-4.8 gtk
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:120:6:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Ptr ()’
            with actual type ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
In the first argument of ‘gtk_plug_new’, namely
  ‘(fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘gtk_plug_new
     (fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:137:6:
Couldn't match expected type ‘Ptr ()’
            with actual type ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
In the second argument of ‘\ (Display arg1) arg2
                             -> withForeignPtr arg1
                                $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_new_for_display argPtr1 arg2’, namely
  ‘(fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘(\ (Display arg1) arg2
      -> withForeignPtr arg1
         $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_new_for_display argPtr1 arg2)
     display
     (fromNativeWindowId (fromMaybe nativeWindowIdNone socketId))’

Graphics/UI/Gtk/Embedding/Plug.chs:151:3:
Couldn't match type ‘Ptr ()’ with ‘Maybe DrawWindow’
Expected type: IO (Maybe DrawWindow)
  Actual type: IO (Ptr ())
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘(\ (Plug arg1)
      -> withForeignPtr arg1 $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_get_id argPtr1)
     (toPlug self)’
In the expression:
  liftM toNativeWindowId
  $ (\ (Plug arg1)
       -> withForeignPtr arg1 $ \ argPtr1 -> gtk_plug_get_id argPtr1)
      (toPlug self)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
```

I previously had Haskell's [`gtk`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk) library and [`threadscope`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threadscope) application installed and running before I updated my Haskell platform from `ghc 7.8.4` to `ghc 7.10.2`.  At first I assumed an installation conflict, but I've repeatedly removed the Haskell platform from my system using the [thorough removal instructions](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-March/090170.html) and reattempted the [`threadscope`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/threadscope) installation with no success. I've even removed and re-installed the underlying `gtk+` and related packages using `homebrew`, again no success.

I'm not sure where the types `Ptr ()` and `Maybe DrawWindow` originate and therefore where the conflict could be coming from. Any ideas on what could be going wrong would be welcome!

Answer (score 3):

maybe you could try to install gtk with this line

`cabal install gtk -fhave-quartz-gtk`

Comment: Stack variant: `stack install --flag gtk:have-quartz-gtk threadscope`

Answer (score 1):

There is a recipe for installing GTK and threadscope at edsko's blog:

http://www.edsko.net/2015/03/09/sandboxes-revisited/

Search the page for "GTK sandbox".

**Update**

I was able to build threadscope using the above instructions with ghc-7.10.2.

The specific commands I used:

```
export PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig
brew install gtk+                      # installed gtk+-2.24.25
brew install poppler                   # installed poppler-0.35.0
cabal sandbox init
cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
cabal install gtk
cabal install poppler --with-gcc=gcc-4.9 --extra-include-dirs=/usr/local/include
cabal install threadscope
```

The specific versions of packages installed in the sandbox:

```
cairo-0.13.1.0
ghc-events-0.4.4.0
gio-0.13.1.0
glib-0.13.2.1
gtk-0.13.9
hashtables-1.2.0.2
pango-0.13.1.0
poppler-0.13.1
utf8-string-1.0.1.1
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response!  Sadly this resulted in the same errors as above during the build of gtk.

Comment: Are you using GHC 7.10.2? The above recipe builds threadscope in a sandbox, so you can follow it without disturbing your installed packages if you are currently on a different version of GHC.

Comment: Yes, I'm using GHC 7.10.2, and I'm very confused why the recipe didn't work, since a sandbox was my sure thing of last resort.

Comment: Some ideas: perform a `cabal update`; use a cabal.config to lock down the versions of the above packages.

Comment: The key for me was to do cabal install gtk -fhave-quartz-gtk as suggested above